# Query about Javascript execution sequence

Tags: javascript, html

I have written the following code in JavaScript:

```
var num=1;
var a=0;
while(a==0){
  num +=1;
  //some logic
  //some logic

  validate();
  alert(num);
}

function validate(){
  //some logic
  //some logic
  if(num==2){
    a=1;
  }
  //some logic
  //some logic
}
```

Here I am getting alert of `1, 2, 3..` but `a` is not becoming `1`. I have observed that `validate();` function is not completed, but the execution is moved to next iteration. Could anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: if(num=2) is wrong - always true, I think you need if(num === 2)

Answer (score 3):

Your `if` statement is assigning a value to `num` not checking it. You have `num=2` which will always be true, you need `num===2`.

Furthermore, if you would like to get 1, 2, then 3 you need to initially set `num` to `0` (`var num=0;`) and also check `num` against `3` instead of `2` in your `if` statement (`num === 3`)

Your updated code:

```js
var num = 0;
var a = 0;
while (a === 0) {
  num += 1;
  validate();
  alert(num);
}

function validate() {
  if (num === 3) {
    a = 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Here problem is a is not becoming 1 becz validate function is not completely exectued but while loop is moving to next iteration.

Comment: @ShanmukhaPhaneendraGajula ,  a becomes 1 when the condition in the if statement is true. What is the problem?